# STDERR Meteor app crash with exit 8 after adding new collection (now just crashing repeatedly?)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, stderr, meteor-collections

Hello world: this is my first stackoverflow question. After searching through other questions and the Meteor documentation I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm working with a clone of the scotch.io meteor-polling app, and I wanted to add a new Mongo collection, which started throwing errors(STDERRs with no messages) when I tried to run the app with it included. So, I removed all references to the collection: my code is the same as it was when it was working properly with just one collection, and I'm still getting errors. Very puzzled. Tried Meteor reset and update to no avail.

here's my repo: https://github.com/abraxasrex/meteor-polling

the code that starting giving errors is the current master.

I'm fairly certain from my debugging that it was either the insertion of the collection or adding votes=[] to newpoll in client/components/poll-form.js(?)

Answer (score 1):

The error logs mention msavin:mongol.

```
TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object [object Object] is not a function
at Package (packages/meteortoys_toykit/packages/meteortoys_toykit.js:290:1)
```

If you remove that you'll have your app working again.

Comment: holy crap. thank you. Were those error logs returned to you in the git bash? Mine were just returning stderr with dated number strings.

Comment: yeah that excerpt is from the command line after running meteor.